# onclick not firing for submit input when attached using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

html:

```
<input id="save "type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

javascript that register onclick (IsValid is a function that validates before submiting, returns true of false)

```
$('#save').click(function () {  
 return IsValid();
});
```

Note that this exact same code works if I write:

```
 <input id="save "type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='javascript: IsValid();'/>
```

This is another option without modifying the markup (createForm is the form)

```
$('#createForm').submit(function () {   
 return IsValid();
});
```

Why $('').click is not registering my event handler?

Form looks like this:

```
 <form method="post" id="createForm" class="well" action="/ScheduleWorkDay/Create" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Comment: Show us a demo on http://JSFiddle.net where the problem persists.

Comment: Have you put your code within document ready handler?

Comment: I think that you may need a `preventDefault` on the click. As @Amaan said, jsFiddle would really help.

Comment: is this your actual code? because `id="save "` could be the problem

Comment: MrOBrian is right. The problem was that <input id="save " had an extra space. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MrOBrian was right. The problem was that

```
 <input id="save "
```

had an extra space in the id name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler isn't registering because there are no handlers on the form with the id `save`, but there is a `save` (with a space).  Remove the space.

```
<input id="save" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary"/>

$('#save').click(function () {  
   return IsValid();
});
```

should work without issues.

[A jsFiddle showing it working](http://jsfiddle.net/NBqYm/1/)

Comment: what do you mean? There is no space in save id

Comment: In your supplied code you have `<input id="save "type="submit"`  Notice the transposed double quote and space before `type`

Comment: In that example there is no form. I think that the problem is related with the form submission. The form is submitted without firing the event

Comment: I disagree.  I updated the fiddle, added a form.  If you set IsValid to return "false" no post occurs, if you set it to "true", a post occurs.

Comment: That's true, I see it works, but it didn't help to me to solve the problem. MrOBrian did

Comment: You mean by saying there was a space in the ID like you denied in your first comment? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that your id has a space or you have not used document.ready()

here is the working demo

```
<input id="save" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary"/>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#save').click(function () {  
 alert("invalid");
 });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NS8xy/)